# JavaScript to restrict users to type only time range in a textbox

Tags: javascript

I want users to only type time in the format of hh:mm-hh:mm in the following textbox. How can I do this with JavaScript without accepting another characters?

```
    <input type="text" id="TBMonday" size="7" style="text-align: center; background: #f2f2f2; border- 
    style: none; color: #4CAF50; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10px" placeholder="hh:mm-hh:mm">
```

Comment: `input type="time" id="TBMonday" required>` ?

Comment: TBMonday is not required @Mister Jojo